# What is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, configurationmanager

I'm using [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot), as a sample Authentication to try out. What I want to know is what happens in [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/blob/master/SampleAADv1Bot/Dialogs/ActionDialog.cs#L45) line. i.e. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"])`. Would somebody be kind enough to explain it?

Comment: information stored in web.config?

Comment: @Lei Yang Oh yes. :) Thank you. So is it a common value or we can change it? What is the purpose of the `ResourceId`?

Comment: it is a .net builtin mechanism to define some settings before the application starts, without recompiling. see [msdn configurationmanager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default configurations for your application in web.config file and access them using the [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

e.g.

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="highestScore" value="200" />
        <add key="defaultSport" value="Cricket" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Code**

```
int maxScore = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["highestScore"]);
string Sport = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultSport"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveDirectory.ResourceId` app setting for the AuthBot example you referenced is:

```
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ResourceId" value="https://graph.windows.net/" />
```

The reason the .ResourceId is `graph.windows.net` as opposed to `graph.microsoft.com` is explained some here: https://github.com/matvelloso/AuthBot/pull/10

> They are both valid. It only depends on which one you configure your
>   application in AAD for. Not everybody has Office 365 and therefore not
>   everybody will have graph.microsoft.com so I'd rather just leave it
>   with the option that is more likely going to work for most people
>   --Matt Velloso